# Remover elemento duplicado de array

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [forn_nome_fantasia] =>   FORNECEDOR TESTE
        [class_nvl4_descricao] =>   DESPESAS COM FRETES
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [forn_nome_fantasia] => DJ/ DESEO -SALA DE ESTAR 
        [class_nvl4_descricao] =>   DESPESAS COM FRETES

    )
)
```

Observe que os valores na chave `class_nvl4_descricao` são iguais. Eu quero remover essa chave quando ela for repetida. De preferência remover todos e deixar só um.

Queria que ficasse assim:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
   (
    [forn_nome_fantasia] =>   FORNECEDOR TESTE
    [class_nvl4_descricao] =>   DESPESAS COM FRETES
   )

 [1] => Array
   (
    [forn_nome_fantasia] => DJ/ DESEO -SALA DE ESTAR 
    [class_nvl4_descricao] =>   ''

  )
)
```

Comment: Coloque um exemplo do resultado para ficar mais fácil de entender o seu problema.

Comment: Vc quer verificar só essa chave "class_nvl4_descricao" ou a outra tb "forn_nome_fantasia"?

Comment: Só a chave `class_nvl4_descricao`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para a lógica que está a tentar implementar pode percorrer todos os arrays que tem dentro do principal e para cada um deles verificar se contem o valor que procura utilizando a função `array_search`. Esta função devolve a chave associada ao valor ou `false` caso não exista. Quando existe e não é o primeiro elemento que encontra atribui o valor `''` para limpar.

Exemplo de implementação:

```
function removerValoresDuplicadas(&$array, $valor){
    $primeiroEncontrado = false;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i){
        //obtem a chave associada ao valor ou false caso não exista nenhuma
        $chave = array_search($valor, $array[$i]); 

        if ($chave !== false){ //se existe o valor
            if ($primeiroEncontrado === false){ //caso especial para não limpar o primeiro
                $primeiroEncontrado = true;
            }   
            else {
                $array[$i][$chave] = ''; //limpa
            }
        }
    }
}

$dados = Array(
        Array("forn_nome_fantasia" => "FORNECEDOR TESTE",
              "class_nvl4_descricao" => "DESPESAS COM FRETES" ),
        Array("forn_nome_fantasia" => "DJ/ DESEO -SALA DE ESTAR",
              "class_nvl4_descricao" => "DESPESAS COM FRETES" )
    );


removerValoresDuplicadas($dados, "DESPESAS COM FRETES");
print_r($dados);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [forn_nome_fantasia] => FORNECEDOR TESTE
            [class_nvl4_descricao] => DESPESAS COM FRETES
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [forn_nome_fantasia] => DJ/ DESEO -SALA DE ESTAR
            [class_nvl4_descricao] => 
        )

)
```

Repare que construí uma função que recebe o valor que pretende eliminar do array para tornar mais flexível e conseguir facilmente eliminar outros que pretenda

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/0b5Fef)

Answer (score 1):

Este código deixará vazia todas as chaves `class_nvl4_descricao` duplicadas, independentemente que valor seja, deixando apenas a primeira ocorrência:

Considerando o nome da Array-mãe = `$array` (caso for outro nome, basta substituir no código).

```
<?php
foreach($array as $idx => $texto){
   for($x=$idx+1;$x<sizeof($array);$x++){
      if( $array[$idx]['class_nvl4_descricao'] == $array[$x]['class_nvl4_descricao'] ){
         $array[$x]['class_nvl4_descricao'] = '';
      }
   }
}
?>
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/hMo95H).